# I can't create a user through Identity in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm working on a project which is a Rest API. It's done following Clean Architecture. The API is secured by JWT so once you have the token you can modify the models and entities in database. I used Identity for users' credentials. I came across kind of a weird situation! I can't create any users in database. It turned out that The line of the code related to creating new users is not get hit at all through debugging!
Below is the action in Presentation layer (API)

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost, Route("login")]
public IActionResult Login(UserModel model)
{
    _userService.LoginUser(model);
    return Ok(new {token = CreateToken()});
}
```

It points to the LoginUser function in Infrastructure layer

```
public async Task LoginUser(UserModel model)
{
    if(model == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("model");
    if(_productDbContext.Users.Any(c=> c.Email == model.Email))
    {
        await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, false, false);
    }
    else
    {
        var user = new User
        {
            UserName = model.Email,
            Email = model.Email
        };
        Claim claim = new Claim(
            type: ClaimTypes.Role,
            value: model.Email
            );
        await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, claim);
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
    }
}
```

At this point the debugger doesn't hit the last line which is the result variable! And I can't see any errors either!

I thought it might be a problem with the User class, so I added Automapper to the project but still I got the same result!

Answer (score 1):

First, I would strongly suggests you do not to create user if login fails.

Issue is in `await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, claim);` line you can't add claim before creating a user. if you want to see exception you can add try catch block to the function.

If you want proper example for Asp.net core identity with api follow [this](https://github.com/andissanayake/UnifiedApp/tree/version/v1).

Comment: var user = new ApplicationUser
{
    Email = "john@company.com",
    Name = "John"
};

await userManager.CreateAsync(user, "password");
await userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("your-claim", "your-value"));